# How can I make a sub url recognize the theme's favicon, not the main url's theme?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a site that I am making and I am using a sub url (like suburl.site.com) for a development. They are each a store within the same Magento instance. They both have  I put different favicon for each of these in their theme folders, but when I go to the sub url the favicon is for the main url.

How can I make the sub url show the favicon for its theme, not the favicon for the theme of the main url?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Magento By default provide the change the `Favicon Icon` `Store wise` , `Website wise`.

**Step 1:** To change this please login in your Site backend.

**Step 2:** Go to **`System >> Configuration >> General >> Design >> HTML Head >> Favicon Icon`**

**Step 3:** You can switch over the Website at backend and based on that you can set your store wise Favicon Icon.